# python streamlit run issue

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to run streamlit application(python  3.7.3) after installing it shows that error

```
    streamlit hello
  File "<ipython-input-2-c7a1b683aa76>", line 1
    streamlit hello
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This is a console command. It looks like you have typed it into a Python interpreter. What happens if you type it at the command line?

Comment: I show in cmd 'streamlit hello
'streamlit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: That is because the instructions on the Getting Started page are for Linux and you want to run it under Windows. Windows will not look for a shebang inside the file to discover how to run it. It has to be told. Try `python.exe path_to_streamlit\streamlit.py`. If you get the same error message then Windows also needs to be told where your Python interpreter is. Something like `C:...\python37\python.exe`.

Comment: I slow this issue using upgrading steamlit and the previous version of NumPy

Answer (score 18):

```
python -m streamlit run <filename.py>
```

This will work definitely.

Answer (score 4):

In windows

```
py -m streamlit run hello.py
```

Comment: Solution 100%. Worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Copy streamlit files in `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts` and paste them into your `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts` and run your streamlit code in anaconda prompt.

Command to run:

```sh
streamlit run filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like you have misunderstood in where you have to use `streamlit hello`. This command will bring you to the welcome page of streamlit if you have successfully installed streamlit. I assume that you are a beginner. This `streamlit hello` should be entered in command prompt, But not in the Ipython Kernel. But you have entered this command into the Ipython Kernel. Look at [this](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/multipage-apps) to learn how to use `streamlit hello` and how to run a python script with streamlit.

To visit welcome page

```
$ streamlit hello
```

To run python script via streamlit

```
$ streamlit run script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the below command

1. streamlit run filename.py

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
streamlit run hello.py
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try and run it through the command prompt (anaconda prompt). If it tells you that 'streamlit' command cannot be recognised and you are sure you have installed streamlit to your environment, then add Anaconda folder into your Windows path. To do this, go to Advanced System Setting -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables, under 'System Variables' -> Path -> Edit -> New, then copy the path to your Anaconda folder, e.g 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3' and click OK all through. That should work. If it does not, visit https://discuss.streamlit.io